# Create another instance of a service that won't be closed with systemctl stop

Tags: linux, services, systemd, systemctl

I want to create another instance of sshd on another port which won't be closed with systemctl stop, but I don't know how to go about doing it. I don't know much about Linux, so I have only tried copying and changing the name, but that doesn't work. systemctl doesn't start both processes, but it stops both.

I can't edit any of the .service files or anything in etc, var... I only have access to my own user.

Comment: Given the restrictions you describe what you want isn’t possible

Comment: What is the relevance to systemd with this question? Why use systemd to start your service if it shouldn't stop it?